# getting unusual error when creating a string schema type dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a simple data frame.

```
df=spark.createDataFrame(data=[('11s1 ab')],schema=['str'])
```

I get error:

TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>

However if I change the statement to :

```
df=spark.createDataFrame(data=[('11s1 ab',)],schema=['str'])
```

my dataframe is successfully created.

I want to understand why that comma sign matters in data definition tuple in spark.createdataFrame.

Comment: you need to pass a tuple, not string. use `data=[('11s1 ab',)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the document of createDataFrame you can see the data field must be:

```
data: Union[pyspark.rdd.RDD[Any], Iterable[Any], ForwardRef('PandasDataFrameLike')]
```

(1,) or [1] are iterable but (1) would be integer type which is not iterable

Comment: Ah, I get it, to make this answer clearer. (1,) is a tuple, (1) is an integer. Hence it fulfills the iterable requirement.